# No identity found common bin/sh/ error

Tags: xcode, archive, provisioning-profile

I have created app id and also provision profile for my distribution.When i archive or build my app using distribution profile,i got the following error

```
PhaseScriptExecution Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/Htarwara6245/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HSSECrix-cgteuxpjvsdrnhdqwjbwqyoqsqpc/Build/Intermediates/HSSECrix.build/Debug-iphoneos/HSSECrix.build/Script-FB973BA3854BA671C46AFE96.sh
cd /Users/Htarwara6245/Documents/workspace/iOS/HSSECrix
/bin/sh -c /Users/Htarwara6245/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HSSECrix-cgteuxpjvsdrnhdqwjbwqyoqsqpc/Build/Intermediates/HSSECrix.build/Debug-iphoneos/HSSECrix.build/Script-FB973BA3854BA671C46AFE96.sh

mkdir -p /Users/Htarwara6245/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HSSECrix-cgteuxpjvsdrnhdqwjbwqyoqsqpc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HSSECrix.app/Frameworks
rsync -av --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/Htarwara6245/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HSSECrix-cgteuxpjvsdrnhdqwjbwqyoqsqpc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Alamofire.framework" "/Users/Htarwara6245/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HSSECrix-cgteuxpjvsdrnhdqwjbwqyoqsqpc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HSSECrix.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... done
Alamofire.framework/
Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
Alamofire.framework/Info.plist
Alamofire.framework/_CodeSignature/
Alamofire.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeResources

sent 1203761 bytes  received 98 bytes  2407718.00 bytes/sec
total size is 1203264  speedup is 1.00
Code Signing /Users/Htarwara6245/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HSSECrix-cgteuxpjvsdrnhdqwjbwqyoqsqpc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HSSECrix.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework with Identity iPhone Distribution: xxxx (28J87M7DQU)
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 7EC847A7363D5591F3061E94631865E1EB36D1D7 --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements "/Users/Htarwara6245/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HSSECrix-cgteuxpjvsdrnhdqwjbwqyoqsqpc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HSSECrix.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework"
7EC847A7363D5591F3061E94631865E1EB36D1D7: no identity found
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

I am tired of this problem happening.For me searching at the google and do things.Didn't solve out.Any help please?

Comment: can you please share your solution for the above issue as like you I am facing this issue since last 2 days but no luck anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem recently and looks like it was due to on developer portal I have updated provision profile.
So I just delete old provision and download updated version.

`Xcode -> Preferences... -> Accounts -> Choose your Apple ID -> View Details...`

Also sometimes helps deleting Derived Data for this project.

`Window -> Projects -> Choose your project`